# How do I come up with the stats of a weapon?

Tags: game-design

I am working on a game, where mosquito is one of the enemies. I'm trying to evaluate the stats of the Electric Racket (used to kill mosquito in real life)?

How can I come up with the stats for such a weapon?

[image: Electric Racket]

Comment: The stats are whatever your game needs them to be. That may be a out of the legend kind of tier to nothing.

Comment: This is impossible for people to answer without knowing what the rest of your game looks like. Can I say its stats will be `Attack: 5` ? What does that mean for your game?

Comment: The stats are my secondary query. I can make them up later.
I am primarily looking for if such game exists where you have to kill tiny insects or mosquitos; what kinds of weapon do they use? Electric? Bio? Point me towards a game.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. This StackExchange is about making your own game or a mod for an existing one. You should not care if other people may or may not have used an electric racket as a weapon. If such a weapon makes sense in your game, use it. If it doesn't - don't include it. Only you can answer that

Comment: We can't give you a list of games here, that research is part of your own task as game designer... this is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: You may be able to solicit suggestions of games that have featured mosquitos / rackets on the [Software Recommendations StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=game). I can't guarantee they'll consider it on-topic, but they do seem to have a number of questions of the form "suggest a game that has X".

Comment: @DMGregory ["mosquito game"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=mosquito+game) returns no result. Thanks anyways, didnt know about that space.

Comment: When a search doesn't turn up existing questions, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

My approach to game design is to keep things as simple as possible, and then add complexity when it helps me to solve a specific design problem.

You didn't tell us much about your game. Only that it contains mosquitoes, an electric racket and that the goal of the player is to kill the mosquitoes using the electric racket. But you didn't tell us anything about how the player accomplishes that. Is it a game of strategy or skill? Real-time or turn-based? I'll have to make a ton of assumptions in order to answer your question, and most of them are probably wrong.

But in most genres, the most simple solution would be as follows. When the player hits a mosquito with the racket, the mosquito dies. There are no hit points or damage formulas, just a binary dead/alive state. There are also no restrictions on how often the player can use the racket. Each click/tab in the correct location kills the mosquitoes. **At this point of the game's development there is no need for stats**.

Depending on your desired game design goals, that might or might not be sufficient. Perhaps you are fine with that gameplay loop. Or perhaps you aren't. Perhaps you don't want the mosquitoes to always die, but rather that they have a chance to survive. Or perhaps they only get injured and need multiple hits.  Perhaps you want to limit the speed with which the player can swing their racket.

Perhaps you want to add more weapons with different attributes: Affected area, attack frequency, deadliness. You probably either want those weapons to be balanced against each other, so the player can pick one based on personal preference. Or you want some progression system where the player advances from less to more effective weapons. In either case, you need some way to make weapons better or worse in certain aspects. **This is the point where stats come into play**.

- If you want weapons to affect different areas, then the shape and size  of their hurtbox becomes a stat.
- If you want weapons to deal more or less damage, their damage value becomes a stat.
- If you want weapons to have a lower or higher attack frequency, then their cooldown delay becomes a stat.

A good way to design the values for stats like that is to keep them  relative to the stat of the most basic weapon. If you want the electric racket to be the "default weapon", then you would use its stats as a baseline and make the stats of all other weapons lower or higher depending on how they should perform relative to the electric racket. How much lower or higher? Finding that out is the fun part! Because the best way to figure it out is by repeatedly playing your game and adjusting the values until you figured out ideal values.